# Tomcat having extremely high cpu usage

Tags: java, tomcat

I have tomcat 8 and running a web application on tomcat. Recently I noticed my Vsphere client showing alarms for high cpu usage and found that the process responsible for is tomcat. When I restart the tomcat server it is running good, but after some time, the same problem arise. How to solve this issue?

```
/data/IMS/java/bin/java -Djava.util.logging.config.file=/data/IMS/tomcat/conf/logging.properties -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Djdk.tls.ephemeralDHKeySize=2048
```

Comment: Tomcat normally does not do this. Which application are you running on top of it? Does the machine have enough memory?

Comment: Or more appropriately, "The check-engine light is on in my car, how do I fix it"?  The answer is you learn how to troubleshoot your system or you pay someone to do it.  StackOverflow cannot possibly answer the question as it stands now.

Comment: @Henry My java application. Yes it has enough memory.

Comment: Did you consider that your Java application may be the problem?

Comment: @Henry In my other setups it's working fine. No issue whatso ever

Answer (score 2):

This is a broad topic, so I can only really provide you with some pointers on how to debug remote applications.

If you want to get some visibility into what your App is doing you can use a tool like Visual VM. Visual VM can profile cpu and memory usage, see details [here](https://visualvm.github.io/). In order to do profiling you need to:

1. Enable JMX on Tomcat. Docs on how to do this for Tomcat 8 are [here](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/monitoring.html).
2. Run Visual VM and point it at your Tomcat server's JMX connection. Tutorial [here](http://www.theserverside.com/tutorial/Configuring-VisualVM-to-connect-to-the-app-server).
3. Do some cpu usage profiling and look at memory usage to get a better idea about what is happening. Formulate some hypotheses and test them out. Repeat the process until you stumble upon a solution.

If I had to guess what was going wrong, I would say memory usage is gradually increasing over time, and garbage collection starts taking a long time.

Comment: If it is as you guess, what will be a possible solution?

Comment: First step is to validate if it is the root cause. Trying solutions before you have any evidence to believe they will work will ultimately consume much more of your time than a proper debugging session would. You can quickly check garbage collection time by using jstat https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstat.html . If there is a lot of time spent garbage collecting you can increase the memory available to Tomcat.

Comment: Ok, one more question. Can we adjust the log level in tomcat?

Comment: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/logging.html

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'll update you back as soon as I have something substantial.